# Is it okay to enjoy Christmas lights?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, children-parenting, christianity, lighting, non-jewish-holidays

My daughter is always talking about how she hates everything Christmas, including the lights on the houses.  I am trying to encourage her that she can like non religious things like the lights, so that she can comfortably live in America.

Is there anything wrong with enjoying Christmas lights?

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but the lights are not non-religious.  The purpose of the lights is so that santa can find your house.  Along with other pagan reasons and and a history of lights decorating the christmas tree.

Comment: @avi [Citation needed]

Comment: Source is http://www.amazon.com/Holly-Reindeer-Colored-Lights-Christmas/dp/0618067868

Comment: Maybe someone should go visit christianity.SE and ask if the lights are religiously significant or not.

Comment: I just noticed that it's been asked.  Link: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4887/what-is-the-religious-significance-of-christmas-lights

Comment: @avi Is Santa pagan?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on my research (see below), Christmas lights are **entirely secular,** and therefore there is **no** problem whatsoever with looking at or enjoying Christmas lights.

Even if the lights are not entirely secular, there still wouldn't be a problem.  The **Shach** (Shulchan Aruch 142:15), based on **Tosfos** and the **Rosh**, writes that it is **permitted** to derive benefit from decorations that are not directly used in idolatrous practices.

[**Rabbi Aharon Tendler**](http://www.jemsem.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=54) directly addresses this issue, and rules that one **may** look at and enjoy Christmas lights, but he doesn't think it's appropriate to do so. His reasoning is as follows (quoted in full; emphasis mine):

> The only prohibition to look at Christmas lights might be is they are used for Avodah Zara, and that you are actually benefiting from them by looking at them. Even if we assume that Christianity is Avodah Zara, the lights are not part of their worship, to the best of my knowledge. Also, most lights that are in urban areas, such as in malls and department stores are not part of a religious service at all, but rather used as a way to attract buyers to come shop. Additionally, merely looking at them would not be considered a Hana'ah (benefit). Consequently, there is **no Issur to look at Christmas lights** if you happen to be passing by them. I don't think that it would be appropriate to specifically stop for the purpose of admiring them, but I'd be hard pressed to find a basis upon which to rule that even that would be forbidden according to Halacha.

---

Based on my research, the modern practice of decorating the outside of the house with Christmas lights is entirely secular, and in fact can be traced back to a *marketing stunt* by Thomas Edison's Edison Electric Light Company!  (Sources: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_lights), [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/christmaslights.html), [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/5425395/christmas-lights-the-brief-and-strangely-interesting-history-of), [The History of Christmas Lights](http://mymerrychristmas.com/2005/lights.shtml))

The secular nature of the lights continues to this day.  As a [professor at Yale](http://www.historymatters.appstate.edu/sites/default/files/christmaslights.pdf) states,

> "One of the key aspects of  the American Christmas light display is its secular
> nature.  Although some people do utilize lighting for religious exaltation — for example
> with illuminated outdoor nativity scenes[1] — the vast majority do not directly associate light displays with religion.  Christmas lights have maintained many of their original nonreligious meanings..."

([1] Note how he only says that some people use lights to *depict* religious scenes.  The lights themselves are not religious in nature.)

The practice of placing lights on the Christmas tree is older, and while the tree has Christian symbolism, the lights themselves do *not.*

> The first decorated tree was at Riga in Latvia, in 1510. In the early 16th century, Martin Luther is said to have decorated a small Christmas Tree with candles, to show his children how the stars twinkled through the dark night. ([Source](http://www.christmasarchives.com/trees.html))
>
> The use of special lights on Christmas originally started with putting small candles on Christmas Trees in the home. Christmas Tree traditions go back to a Germany in the 1500s, and it’s believed the idea to put lights on the trees was started by Martin Luther, a famous priest who was inspired by the prettiness of stars twinkling between evergreens while walking home one night. ([Source](http://whyzz.com/why-do-we-put-up-christmas-lights))

While the general practice of lighting lights in the dead of winter can be connected to pagan Winter Solstice rituals, by this point in time any such association has been completely overwhelmed by the increasingly secular nature of the holiday.

---

However, in my humble opinion, a Jew should *not* decorate his own house with such lights at Christmas time, due to issues of "Mar'os Ayin" and "Imitating Gentile Customs."

As an interesting sidenote, there is a not-too-uncommon practice in Israel to decorate the Sukkah with strings of lights - identical to the strings Americans would call "Christmas lights."  I don't know what conclusions can or should be gleaned from this observation.

Comment: Not to mention the Halakhic legality of [this mind-blowing picture.](http://failedmessiah.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451b71f69e201310f45eb3a970c-800wi)

Comment: Shmuel, you are wrong.  But this isn't Christianity.stackExchange.com    The only thing that is wrtting about is the duration for the lights being up, and has nothing to do with what the article states is clearly from way before Thomas Edison was even born!

Comment: What is so mind blowing about it?  They don't know what they are dressed in, becuase unlike in America, Jews are not brought up to worship Christmas

Comment: How in the world does Thanksgiving come into this?  Do Jews not benefit from the colonization of America?

Comment: The oldest neighbhorhood lighting ceremony of Christmas lights in America was continued by this group here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationwide_Festival_of_Light

Comment: Any items even associated with Avoda would be asur see Ben Ish Hai Mase 2.

Comment: @avi : That wikipedia article has nothing at all to do with Christmas lights.  And I quote: "The Nationwide Festival of Light was a grassroots movement formed by British Christians concerned about the development of the permissive society in the UK at the end of the 1960s."

Comment: @avi Maybe you should read the Wikipedia article again, more carefully.  Maybe you should also check out the other sources I've mentioned.  For example, one of the articles explicitely states that the practice of hanging christmas lights outside started with Edison.  "Edison had his incandescent light bulbs pretty well figured out, and was on the lookout for a way to advertise them... To display his invention as a means of heightening Yuletide excitement, he strung up incandescent bulbs all around his Menlo Park laboratory compound." (Source 3 above)

Comment: Shmuel, if you would read the same wiki article completely you would notice that.  " The Holiday Trail of Lights is a joint effort by cities in east Texas and northwest Louisiana that had its origins in the Festival of Lights and Christmas Festival in Natchitoches, started in 1927, making it one of the oldest light festivals in the United States."  (Festival of Lights" then links that wiki article I mentioned before.  The fact that you think there is no connection to Christmas lights just proves that you have not researched this thoroughly

Comment: Missed the firs few lines of the wiki quote to do room:  In the U.S. from the 1960s, beginning in tract housing, it became increasingly the custom to completely outline the house (but particularly the eaves) with weatherproof Christmas lights. Unreleated, is the fact that this is not a custom Thomas Edison invented, it is only one he profited from. The fact that Thomas Edison did lightbulbs does not negate the fact that years before Edison was born people were hanging up lanterns and candles!

Comment: Wikipedia is not the most reliable of sources, and it is known that people try to diminish the Christian aspect of Christmas as much as they can, so that they can enjoy it better. It doesn't negate the fact that Religious Christians very much find significance and meaning in the Christmas lights.   Ideas such as santa being inveted by Coca Cola, or Edison inventing the custom is part of American Folklore.  But any thourough research would discover that these practices existed in Europe for centuries.

Comment: Your conclusion does not follow from the quote.  The question relates to enjoying the "lights on the houses," not the candles hung on indoor Christmas trees.  Edison was indeed the progenitor of the custom to decorate the house with strings of light.

Comment: "Edison was indeed the progenitor of the custom to decorate the house with strings of light."  Then why was the first building ever lit up with lights in England by a rival Lightbulb company?  Sure, Edison was the first American to light lights in America, but he did not invent this custom.

Comment: And lets not forget that many Catholics will not do Christmas decorations or allow their children to mention Santa,  because they view those customs as pagan!

Comment: "first building ever lit up with lights in England..." That was for a play, and had nothing to do with Christmas.  **Thank you for this wonderful discussion.  Due to some of your critiques, I have continually revised my answer.  I hope that it will be considered satisfactory to the original questioner, and will remain informative for the general public.  Have a nice day, Shmuel.**

Comment: Please read the entire siman in Shulhan Aruch in Yoreh deah 137 and all your questions will be answered.

Comment: @H'Gabriel 137 or 139?

Comment: Actually 142:15

Comment: Of course Jews should not hang lights at this time of year (an arguable any time of year), I was asking about looking a them and enjoying them.

Comment: @Shmuel. That picture may or may not be "mind-blowing", but it's certainly cute.

Comment: @avi. I've certainly heard of some Christians avoiding Christmas (I was brought up in such a tradition; see also Oliver Cromwell, who banned the celebration in England during his time as Protector), but I've never heard of Catholics doing so. They're generally fairly relaxed about "pagan practices". (I'm Irish, and shall therefore mention that Cromwell was a genocidal bastard, though this is not particularly germane to his views on Christmas.)

Comment: @Shmuel. Calling Martin Luther a "famous priest" is a very impressive bit of understatement.

Comment: @TRiG - It's also succinct.

Comment: About decorating the Sukkah with strings of lights...when I first heard about that, I thought it was brilliant. I was new to keeping Sukkot & the sukkah was pretty much unusable at night (no outdoor lighting there). I hit up K-Mart after Christmas one year & got lights at 90% off. I would not have chosen anything red & green (my first choice was blue & white), but all they had was white. I use 3 strings of the small LED lights & they cast enough light to have dinner inside. Christmas lights are designed to be used safely outdoors, even kept up for weeks & run in the rain. I'm in the US.

Comment: The link you provide to "Rabbi A. Tendler" does not have the passage you quote, which, nonetheless, contradicts your assertion that there is "no problem whatsoever", if only because you explicitly quote him as saying it would be inappropriate to stop and look at them.

Answer (score 8):

It is permissible to enjoy Christmas lights. (See [Ben Ish Hai S"B Mase 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=430&hilite=) who says that they don't have the din of idol worship, [Shulhan Aruch Yoreh Deah 142:15 with Shach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=135&hilite=)). The Ben Ish Hai texts also quote Rav Avraham Danzig in [Hochmat Adam 87:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33594&st=&pgnum=265) which explains that the names of their festivals do not have the same kinds of restrictions as the actual names of their gods. So the idea that the lights are called *Christmas lights* is just like any other name of a person and is of no concern.

Comment: אסור לשמוע כלי שיר של עבודת כוכבים או להסתכל בנוי עבודת כוכבים, כיון שנהנה בראייה
That seems to be talking about objects that are directly used in serving idols.  I don't think that includes Christmas lights.  Even if they're not entirely secular, Christians don't worship them or directly associate them with idolatry like the Trinity.  For example, in the other sections of 142, the Shulchan Aruch talks about knives that were used to slaughter sacrifices to idols, things that were made with parts consecrated to idols.  Christmas lights are at best only indirectly related to serving Avoda Zara.

Comment: נוי means beauty not use of Avoda Zara. It means decorations. Nobody uses decorations to do avoda zara, that's obvious, that's also obvious that Shulhan Aruch was referring to things like xmas lights.

Comment: I understand that.  "Use" was referring to כלי שיר and previous sections in 142. . . I don't think it's that obvious.  Seems to me that he's talking about enjoying the beauty of the actual idols. צ"ע

Comment: Mehila, you are correct. I hope you forgive me. Please look in the Shach who says that it only means things that were worshipped.

Comment: No problem.  For everyone else who might see this, the ש"ך (footnote 33) writes " בנוי אלילים - פי' באלילים עצמם שנעבדו אסור להסתכל בהן לראות נויין אבל צורות שנעשו לנוי ולא לעבוד מבואר בתו' והרא"ש דמותר"

Comment: You are correct as I said before. Ashrecha

Comment: You know, this Shach doesn't necessarily represent the opinion of the Shulhan Aruch. You notice, he quotes the Tosfafot and the Rosh, but that doesn't mean Maran accepts that opinion. As you said before צ"ע. According to Ashkenazim it would be Mutar, and those Sephardim who follow the Ben Ish Hai it may also seem to be Mutar.

Comment: Also, see the Birke Yosef on this. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14613&st=&pgnum=44&hilite=

Comment: I think we are asking the question backwards.  The question in my mind, is:  Is it possible for Christians to celebrate Christmas without chrismas lights?  Would they say its ok?  If so, then this answer works, if not, then it is a davar avoda zarah.

Comment: The sources you're linking seem to imply if anything the exact opposite of what you seemingly cite them as saying(?)

Answer (score 1):

Christmas lights are a religious symbol.  They are not secular.  (But, obviously, secular people have adopted Christmas lights for their own purposes.)

In this case, you should be learning from your daughter, as [*Malachi* 3:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.24?lang=bi) says will happen. There is no reason why you should be trying to make your daughter feel comfortable with Christian practices, or feel comfortable living in America, while the perfectly-good option of moving to Israel is available.

Gd said ["Lech L'cha"](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=1&CHAPTER=12), and the opportunity to do so is wide open.

Comment: On the contrary, Christmas in America has become almost entirely secularized.  Heck, the modern-day conception of Santa was pretty much [invented by Coca~Cola!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa#20th_century)

Comment: Re Israel: There are 123,000 Christian Arabs living in Israel proper, and more of European descent. (Source: Israeli Ministry of Foreign Affairs).  However, their numbers are magnified due to fact that Israel has these large churches, the birthplace of Jesus, and other Christian holy site.  Tons of tourist flood into Israel around Christmas-time, seeking the spirituality of the country.  Which means that Christmas in Israel is actually far *more* religious in spirit and character than it is in, say, Brooklyn.

Comment: Shmeul your knowlege about Santa Clause is wrong... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas

Comment: Shmuel, I live in Israel, and I live next door to a chrisitian village.  Lights exist but are completely not all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I enjoyed looking at the lights in the end of December growing up out of town, [Rav Avigdor Miller](https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-xmas-lights/) isn't too keen on the idea to say the least:

> It’s very wrong to admire anything that is in any way connected to
> avodah zarah. Of course not! תזרם כמו דוה – “You should throw it away
> like something that is unclean” (Yeshai’ah 30:22). It’s disgusting.
> And even if you don’t think so, you must tell yourself that it’s
> disgusting. You must train yourself to think properly. The lights are
> disgusting. Chas v’shalom to admire the lights.
>
> I don’t want to talk in public about what they’re celebrating but it’s
> one of the most shameful things in history. A child was born from a
> woman who said, “It’s not from my husband,” and that’s celebrated all
> over the world as the happiest event! Disgusting! He was born from a
> woman who said, “I admit, it’s not from my husband.” It’s the worst
> kind of birth that could be and they want to celebrate it with
> lights?! TAPE # E-211 (December 1999)

Comment: Out of which town?

Comment: One of the farm towns outside of Philly - apparently the wide open spaces of land made for amazing areas for holiday light shows.

Comment: Yes, it is disgusting. On the other hand, Christmas lights are secular in nature and therefore, do not celebrate adultery anymore. We can enjoy them.

Comment: @TurkHill The lights can certainly be a beautiful spectacle which are quite enjoyable. At the same time, Rav Avigdor Miller says we shouldn't. I'm not big enough to give an opinion - it seems like you're following Rav Aharon Tendler quoted above. Rav Avigdor Miller clearly seems to disagree.

Comment: @NJM There are different opinions on the matter but I generally agree with the more lenient ones, like Rav Tendler.

Comment: @NJM Also, I will add that Christmas is the only holiday where the whole world celebrates the birth of one Jew.